# How to GET from a model, showing its related models' details in the JSON response?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am writing a small system of which a `Transaction` has an `Account` and `Category` related to it. Currently I'm using `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` in the `TransactionSerializer`. I need to, when `GET`ing all the transactions or just one, to return the related `Account` and `Category` details in the JSON response. By using `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`, the response is alike this:

```
class TransactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    account = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    category = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)

# output:
[
  transaction: {
    id: 1,
    account: 1
    category: 3,
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

To bring the details the related account and category, I've done the following in the `TransactionSerializer`:

```
class TransactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    account = AccountSerializer()
    category = CategorySerializer()

# output:
[
  transaction: {
    id: 1,
    account: { id: 1, name: "Foo", ... }
    category: { id: 3, name: "Bar", ... },
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

But then I cannot create a new Transaction. It shows an error saying `account` and `category` are required. I've tried moving the fields to `read_only` within the serializer, but then another error says these fields should be within `fields` list.

Full `views.py` of transactions:

```
class TransactionList(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        user_id = request.user.pk
        transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).order_by('-created_at')
        serializer = TransactionSerializer(transactions, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        account = Account.objects.get(pk=request.data['account'])
        category = Category.objects.get(pk=request.data['category'])
        serializer = TransactionSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(user=request.user, account=account, category=category)

            return Response(serializer.data, status=HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class TransactionDetail(APIView):
    def get(self, request, pk):
        try:
            transaction = Transaction.objects.get(pk=pk)
            serializer = TransactionSerializer(transaction)

            return Response(serializer.data)
        except:
            raise Http404
```

`urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.TransactionList.as_view(), name="transaction_list"),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.TransactionDetail.as_view(), name="transaction"),
]
```

`models.py`:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, default=None)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, default=None)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default="0.0")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=256, default=None, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

So this is my problem. How do I create a new Transaction, assigning an account and category by ID, and yet when retrieving all, bring all the details?

Comment: Show your views and URLs.

Comment: Question updated with views and URLs files code.

Comment: Can you provide your models?

Comment: But... you're defining get and post methods, and you reference the serializer explicitly in each. What's stopping you just using a different one in each method? I assumed you were using a viewset, where you'd have to do something clever like override `get_serializer_class`, but here there is literally nothing to do other than to use the serializer you want. What's the problem?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, the problem is if I attempt to create a new Transaction by leaving its serializer as in the example #2, an error will happen saying `account` and `category` are required. But, if I use `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`, when I `GET` the transactions, they will not have the objects for `Account` and `Category` in the response. Perhaps I should use a viewset, then?

Comment: You should *use a different serializer* in get from the one you use in post.

Comment: Precisely. Thank you.

Comment: The first thing to note is that from the code given above you have _ForeignFields_ and for that purpose you must explicity *create* them when creating a serializer. You would use _create(self, validated_data)_ to add any extra details into the object before saving into each model field just like **validated_data does.

Answer (score 0):

Creating two serializers, one for listing and one for creating did the trick.

```
class ListTransactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    account = AccountSerializer()
    category = CategorySerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = '__all__'


class CreateTransactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    account = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    category = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create and return a new 'Transaction' instance
        :param validated_data:
        :return: Transaction
        """
        return Transaction.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        pass
```

Answer (score -1):

First rewrite models to related name fileds for rest implementation.

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, related_name="user_serialzer")
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, default=None, related_name="account_serialzer")
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, default=None, related_name="category_serialzer")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default="0.0")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=256, default=None, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Then serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fileds = '__all__'


class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fileds = '__all__'

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fileds = '__all__'

class SerializerTransactions(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_serialzer = UserSerializer(many=True)  
    account_serialzer = AccountSerializer(many=True)    
    category_serialzer = CategorySerializer(many=True)  

    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fileds = ('id', 'name', 'user_serialzer', 'account_serialzer', 'category_serialzer',)
```

Comment: Hi. The same error persists. It will say all three fields user, category and account are required.